# How I can converting from TSQLT to HL7 (V2) format

Tags: t-sql, hl7-v2

I already create export T-SQL in CSV.
Now I need to export in HL7 V2 format.
Do you know what tools are available?
Can someone share some sql code as a starting point?

Thanks
JCS

Answer (score 0):

If you already have an exported CSV using T-SQL, then I guess you can use Mirth (NextGen) Connect as the interface engine. This allows you to pick up the CSV file then create an HL7 v2 message from there.

This link should help you: https://github.com/nextgenhealthcare/connect

The good thing with this is this is designed for healthcare interoperability, which supports HL7 v2, FHIR and other data types like CSV, JSON, delimited text, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Mirth Connect will help you with that. You must create a "File Reader" channel and map out your CSV headers. Then you can define the destination and type of connector (transmission method: HTTP Sender, FileWriter, Database Writer, TCP Sender, Web Service Sender, etc) of your choice and transform your CSV into a HL7 v2 message to be sended.

Also, you can create a channel to query the data straight from the database by using a Database Reader and build your HL7 v2 message starting from there without the CSV extraction and save some time.